# I want to get the data from a async method as a string but i get instance of future<dynamic>

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I tried this logic. With it, I can print the needed data but I cannot save it to a local variable.

```
{
   var temp;
      //gets the user details using firestore and uid
      final result = firestoreServices.getUserDetails(user.uid);
      result.then((data) {
        temp = data['role'];
      }, onError: (e) {
        print(e);
      });
      print("temp: --> $temp");
     
      return UserModel(uid: user.uid, role: userRole);
}
```

if I print temp it prints null.

I don't wanna use future builder. Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{
   var temp;
      //gets the user details using firestore and uid
      final result = await firestoreServices.getUserDetails(user.uid);
      temp = data['role'];
      print("temp: --> $temp");
      return UserModel(uid: user.uid, role: userRole);
}
```